# Confusion with modeling a trigonometric function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am studying trigonometry on Khan Academy and came across this problem:

The daily low temperature in Guangzhou, China, varies over time in a periodic way that can be modeled by a trigonometric function.
The period of change is exactly $1$ year. The temperature peaks around July 26 at $78°F$, and has its minimum half a year later at $49°F$. Assuming a year is exactly 365 days, July 26 is $\frac { 206 }{ 365 } $
​​  of a year after January 1.
Find the formula of the trigonometric function that models the daily low temperature $T$ in Guangzhou **t years** after January 1, 2015. Define the function using radians.

$T(t)=$

---

So the steps I took are:

1) Finding the amplitude:
$$\frac { 78-49 }{ 2 } =14.5$$

2) Finding the midline: 
$$\frac { 78+49 }{ 2 } =63.5$$

3) Figuring out whether to use cosine or sine:

I figured that I can treat July 26th as the beginning of the year and then shift the function to make it the 206th day of the year. So I used cosine. Since at $0$, a cosine function is at its max value.

4) The period:
$1$ year is a period so it must be $$\frac { 2\pi  }{ 365 } $$

5) The function without the shift is now:
$$14.5cos(\frac { 2\pi  }{ 365 } u)+63.5$$

6) Now I must find the value of $u$ in order to properly shift the function. I imagine that this must be $t-206$ since it is $206$ days after January 1.

I feel like I must be missing something here or got one of the steps wrong. Please guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you mostly have the right idea.  The thing you forgot is that $t$ is the number of **years**, not days.  The answer you should get is
$$
14.5 \cos \left(2 \pi \left(t - \frac{206}{365} \right)\right) + 63.5
$$

Comment: can you please explain this?

Comment: All of your problems come down to the fact that you're not keeping track of the units of $t$.  Let's start here: what is the period of our function, and why is it **not** $365$?

Comment: The period is one year and its not 365 since then.. it would keep track of individual days rather than years?

Comment: You're starting to get it, but your phrasing is strange so I'll spell it out: $T(t)$ is a function that takes the number of years since January 1, 2015 ($t$) and gives the temperature at that time.  The statement "the temperature has a period of one year" is the same as saying "at every number of years $t$, $T(t+1)$ (the temperature one year after $t$) will be equal to $T(t)$ (the temperature at time $t$)".

Comment: I now see where I made the mistake. I should've actually done $\frac { 2\pi  }{ 1 } $ as the period and then shifted the function by the fraction of a year that July 26 is after January 1

Comment: If $t$ measured days instead of years, then it would indeed make sense to say that the period is 365, since we would have to increase $t$ by 365 in order to get the same value for $T$.

Comment: Exactly! you're all set.